# getting 404 error in english home page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, language

As mentioned in the title i am getting an 404 error in my english store view in `magento` 1.9. I had until recently one language in my shop and then decided to add english too. I created a second home page , assigned it to the english page and then copied in the design section all the data that i had in the default home page. But when i switch from the other language to english i get the 404. The rest menu works pretty fine. Any ideas/advice on how to resolve this??

Comment: Please check your /var/log/system.log and paste few last lines after refreshing that page. Give us website code, store code, store view code. Do you have CMS page set as home enabled for that store view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed that on my own, i notice that the identifier was changed so i renamed it again and the problem solved. I post my answer just to help others too, with the same issue.

Comment: I have created store, using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10755182/8416476. the page return 404 error. may i know the store possibilities error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the right homepage for each store view under `System->Configuration->Web->Default Pages->CMS Home Page`. Make sure the page you set for each store view is active in that store view.

Comment: my idea to creating another home page for my english store view is it legit?

Comment: Yep. it's legit. Make sure you edit the field I mentioned in my answer and set you new page as homepage for the EN store view.

Comment: i did that but i get the same 404 error. As mentioned in my question my menu works pretty fine.